# java 8 auto update from u60 to u181: there is JRE only

Tags: java, auto-update, java-home

On windows, current java version is 1.8.0_60.
Java auto update: updated java version to 1.8.0_181.

```
C:\Program Files\java\

jdk1.8.0_60
jre1.8.0_181
jre1.8.0_60
```

There is JRE directory for the new version 1.8.0_181, but no JDK directory. What should JAVA_HOME be set to? For development with gradle build, both java and javac are needed.

Comment: Set it to a path with the JDK, and you may turn off the auto updates.

Comment: I believe `java` comes with the JDK (check its `bin` directory), so you might not need the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and install the jdk manually, because it will not autoupdated - only the jre will.